# Will hard drive spin if only a power cord attached ?

Tags: hard-drive

If a hard drive is attached with a power cord (but without a SATA cable), will it spin ?

My primary concern is "will it degrade the hard drive overtime as if it has been used ?" because I just want keep it there just in case other drives fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

If you are planning on keeping the HDD as a backup but not making any connection to the machine (SATA), there is no purpose to have power plugged in.

You will need to open up your machine to plug in either, regardless.

While it will degrade, it is nothing worth worrying about because the real work is done in Reading/Writing.  Of which, you will not be doing if you only have power plugged in.

**@computercarguy** also makes a valid point of possible power faults or surges causing motor failure.  Which is another good reason to consider leaving the spare HDD unplugged until it is needed.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I've had HD motors get dead spots after (many, many) years of use, so I'd recommend leaving the power cable unplugged.  This also reduces your power consumption, and reduces the likelihood of a damaged HD if it ever has a (near) lightening strike or other massive power spike.